# I am getting TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str while using tkinter, please tell me how can fix this

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was creating a program that can cipher a message but while trying to use tkinter to add GUI to it i am getting the following error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
the code is given below.
please tell me how can i fix this.

```
from tkinter import *
key2 = {
    "G": "A",
    "H": "B",
    "I": "C",
    "J": "D",
    "K": "E",
    "L": "F",
    "M": "G",
    "N": "H",
    "O": "I",
    "P": "J",
    "Q": "K",
    "R": "L",
    "S": "M",
    "T": "N",
    "U": "O",
    "V": "P",
    "W": "Q",
    "X": "R",
    "Y": "S",
    "Z": "T",
    "A": "U",
    "B": "V",
    "C": "W",
    "D": "X",
    "E": "Y",
    "F": "Z",
    " ": " ",
    "5": "1",
    "6": "2",
    "7": "3",
    "8": "4",
    "9": "5",
    "0": "6",
    "1": "7",
    "2": "8",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "9"
}
key = {
    "A": "G",
    "B": "H",
    "C": "I",
    "D": "J",
    "E": "K",
    "F": "L",
    "G": "M",
    "H": "N",
    "I": "O",
    "J": "P",
    "K": "Q",
    "L": "R",
    "M": "S",
    "N": "T",
    "O": "U",
    "P": "V",
    "Q": "W",
    "R": "X",
    "S": "Y",
    "T": "Z",
    "U": "A",
    "V": "B",
    "W": "C",
    "X": "D",
    "Y": "E",
    "Z": "F",
    " ": " ",
    "1": "5",
    "2": "6",
    "3": "7",
    "4": "8",
    "5": "9",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "1",
    "8": "2",
    "9": "3",
    "0": "4"
}
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x670")
root.minsize(300, 670)
root.maxsize(670, 300)
output = " "

def zero_or_one():
    def incase_0():
       output = ""
       for ch in e1.get():
         output += key.get(ch)
       l1 = Label(root, text=output, width=49)
       l1.grid(column=0)
    def incase_1():
       output= ""
       for ch in e1.get():
         output += key2.get(ch)
       l1 = Label(root, text=output, width=49)
       l1.grid(column=0)
    if e.get() == '0':
        e1 = Entry(root, width=49)
        e1.grid(column=0)
        but = Button(root, text="god damn it", command=incase_0)
        but.grid(column=0)

    elif e.get() == '1':
        e1 = Entry(root, width=49)
        e1.grid(column=0)
        but = Button(root, text="god damn it", command=incase_1)
        but.grid(column=0)
    elif e.get() == "quit":
        exit()
    elif e.get() == 'help':
        txt = '''
                press 0 to cipher a message
                press 1 to decipher a message 
                type help to get instructions
                type quit to close program'''
        l1 = Label(root, text=txt, width=49)
        l1.grid(column=0)


 e = Entry(root, width=49)
 e.grid(column=0)
 b = Button(root, text="press", command=zero_or_one)
 b.grid(row=1, column=0)




 root.mainloop()
```

sorry if there are any indentation problems withe code SO did not indented it properly

Comment: Please always provide a [mre], as well as the **complete** error traceback. We don't want to try and guess what line caused the error.

Comment: `key = { v:k for k,v in key2.items() }` would shrink your code by approx 50% and is less error prone then what you did. Also look into str.maketrans, str.translate:  `code = str.maketrans("ABCD123","CDAB312")` and `print("AACD2".translate(code))` results in printing `CCAB1`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me explain you the error. The error tends to say that you are concatenating (or combining) a string with a `None`, which is not possible. So, for finding the fix, you have to identify the part of the code where the error is occurring.

So, by my analysis, I found two places where the strings are concatenating, and as `Python` is a interpreter language, the complete error traceback is the most informative and beneficial for the solver as suggested by @Thierry Lathuille.

```py
output = ""
for ch in e1.get():
    output += key.get(ch)

output = ""
for ch in e1.get():
    output += key2.get(ch)
```

I believe you are using `Entry` widget of the tkinter. The above will be prone to huge amount of bugs and errors, as if someone types a special character or the character not included as the `key` in your dictionary `key` and `key2`, the `get()` function of dictionary will return `None`.

So, how to fix it?
It is rather simple as you have thought. There are multiple ways to simplify your code a bit, but I'll leave it you for consideration. As for the solution, you can add an `if` to check whether the `key` exists.

```py
output = ""
for ch in e1.get():
    if ch in key: # Returns True if the key exists, otherwise False
        output += key.get(ch)
```

Comment: could get rid of the if statement and simply use `output += key.get(ch,ch)` - and probably should switch to output = [] and output = ''.join(output) - string concat is wasteful :)